# I want to be able to view the CCTV screen on the web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

### I want to be able to view the CCTV screen on the web.

I have been working on a project that allows the ip camera to be viewed on the web.
Then I was asked to make Coaxial camera visible on the web.
So I decided to use DVR.
First, I connected the DVR to the router.
Then the input of the coaxial camera is received by the DVR and the DVR transmits the information through the router.
Through this process, i confirmed that rtsp works normally.
But it didn't work on the web.

I am currently using the nginx web server.
and use ffmpeg to send rtsp information to rtmp on my nginx web server.
The web server will then transform it into an hls (index.m3u8) file.
I think something went wrong during this process.

### Nginx RTMP Config

```
# RTMP Config
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
        chunk_size 4000;
        application live{
            live on;
            deny play all;
            push rtmp://localhost/play;
            on_publish http://localhost:3001/api/on-live-auth;
            on_publish_done http://localhost:3001/api/on-live-done;
        }
        application play {
            live on;
            # Turn on HLS
            hls on;
            hls_nested on;
            hls_fragment_naming system;
            hls_path /home/banana/nginx/live;
            hls_fragment 3;
            hls_playlist_length 60;

            # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
            #deny play all;
        }
    }
}
# End RTMP Config
```

### FFMPEG command

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://<cameraIp> -c:v copy -rtsp_transport tcp -preset veryfast -c:a copy -fflags +igndts+genpts -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/<cameraId>
```

### Test results

IP Camera RTSP address = admin:qwerty1.@ssnet4.iptime.org:555/trackID=3

DVR RTSP address = admin:hrd-442s@hwakptz.iptime.org:4524/1

Run the above rtsp addresses in vlc player respectively

Success : IP Camera RTSP address , DVR RTSP address

IP camera HLS address = http://168.131.150.80:4567/live/5c28ae28c6cd0c6c329e1ebc/index.m3u8

DVR HLS address = http://168.131.150.80:4567/live/5c8746c9d7d74a600edf2460/index.m3u8

Run the above rtsp addresses in vlc player respectively

Sucess : IP Camera HLS address

Fail : DVR HLS address

This is the same result on the react player.

```
const streamUrl = `http://168.131.150.80:4567/live/<cameraId>/index.m3u8`;
<ReactPlayer
            onClick={this._onClickFullscreen}
            width={"100%"}
            height={"100%"}
            url={streamUrl}
            playing={true}
            controls={false}
            muted={true}
          />
```

### Question

1. Is there a way to see rtsp directly on the web?
2. What's the problem and what's the other way?

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no why to see RTSP in a web browser without installing a plugin.

The only protocols web browsers support are http, web socket, and webrtx.

Comment: You are right.
So I converted rtsp to rtmp.
After that convert, rtsp's ts file and index.m3u8 file will be created.
I then run the index.m3u8 file path into the url of the react-player.
I was wondering that ip-camera's rtsp works normally, but dvr's rtsp does not work.